# What will gitkraken do when I click the label "mark all resolved"?

Tags: gitkraken

What will git do when I click the label "mark all resolved" on GitKraken  which can resolve merging conflicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitKraken will **add every previously detected conflicting file to the index**, and you'll then have to commit to finish the merge.

This is what you do when you have finished resolving conflicts.

(Do *not* do that if you're unsure all your conflicts are resolved, or else you'll have conflict markers scattered inside your files.)

Comment: which branch will Gitkraken take?

Comment: @蔡仲勋 By default, all happens on the checked out branch, the current branch, the one on which the conflict is ongoing.

Answer (score 1):

*Mark all resolved* is not a git thing, it is a service provided by GitKraken.

It will `git add` the files that have merge conflict, assuming that you have maid the needed modifications by yourself. You **should not do that unless you really have resolved conflicts**.

The git equivalent of *mark all resolved* would be:

```
git add $(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U)
```

Answer (score -4):

It will replace the current changes with origin or pulled branch.